Unable to connect http://127.0.0.1:4723/ on start of Appium
Unable to connect http://127.0.0.1:4723/  on start of Appium.
I want to use Appium Tizen TV Driver to automate the testing of appium-tizen-tv. And for that I am using   https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-tizen-tv-driver
Now When I am starting Appium
I am getting this
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v2.9.0
[Appium] The autodetected Appium home path: /Users/David/.appium
[Appium] Attempting to load driver tizentv...
[Appium] Requiring driver at /Users/David/.appium/node_modules/appium-tizen-tv-driver/build/lib/index.js
[Appium] TizenTVDriver has been successfully loaded in 2.200s
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://0.0.0.0:4723
[Appium] You can provide the following URLs in your client code to connect to this server:
[Appium]    http://127.0.0.1:4723/ (only accessible from the same host)
[Appium]    http://172.16.16.27:4723/
[Appium] Available drivers:
[Appium]   - tizentv@0.11.0 (automationName 'TizenTV')
[Appium] No plugins have been installed. Use the "appium plugin" command to install the one(s) you want to use.

So In When I am using this
http://127.0.0.1:4723/status

I am getting proper response like :
{
  "value": {
    "ready": true,
    "message": "The server is ready to accept new connections",
    "build": {
      "version": "2.9.0"
    }
  }
}

Now when I am using this :
http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub as this required in my code to connect the driver like
driver = new AppiumDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

I am getting this error :
{
  "status": 9,
  "value": {
    "error": "unknown command",
    "message": "The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource",
    "stacktrace": ""
  }
}

Same while running the code as well. Any idea how to fix this.
Here is my code
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    

AppiumDriver driver = null;

    try{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new 
        DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Tizen");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "tv-samsung-8.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "Path of the App"); // need to do with the
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "TizenTV");


        driver = new AppiumDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"),capabilities); // This the place it is failing.
 
        
        
    }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}

Error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<init>(java.net.URI, java.time.Duration, java.time.Duration, org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter, java.net.Proxy, org.openqa.selenium.Credentials)'
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.<init>(AppiumClientConfig.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.defaultConfig(AppiumClientConfig.java:79)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
    at org.android.tizen.BasicProjectTest.main(BasicProjectTest.java:30)

Note : There is one old answer which is 7 years old. Old Question

Can you connect to it with like curl or telnet?

@Hicomputer Yes even by using curl also I am getting the similar error.

you don't need /wd/hub from appium 2.0 so just change to this and it should work
driver = new AppiumDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"),capabilities);


Even same thing I am getting at http://127.0.0.1:4723

What is the new error message ?
